# jQuery onclick pass post variables and reload page

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Can I pass post variables and reload a page on clicking an hyperlink?

To be clear I have something like this. 
`<a href="test.php?name=test">Click</a>`

If javascript is enabled,

I think I can use "event.preventDefault()" to suppress passing as GET variable.

So now onclick, name should be passed as post variable instead of get.

If javascript is disabled,
Then the above should work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do it, by creating a new `form` element, pointing it at the `href` and calling `.submit()` on it.

```
<a class="postlink" href="test.php?name=test">Click</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.postlink').click(function() {
        var form= document.createElement('form');
        form.method= 'post';
        form.action= this.protocol+'//'+this.hostname+this.pathname;
        $.each(this.search.slice(1).split(/[&;]/g), function() {
            var ix= this.indexOf('=');
            if (ix===-1) return;
            var input= document.createElement('input');
            input.type= 'hidden';
            input.name= decodeURIComponent(this.slice(0, ix));
            input.value= decodeURIComponent(this.slice(ix+1));
            form.appendChild(input);
        });
        document.body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

Or you could just do an AJAX request instead and `reload()` the page afterwards if you prefer.

However, I'm not sure why you'd want to do this. What use is a link that's usually POSTed, except when it's not? (Not just when JS is disabled/unavailable or when it's a search engine, but also when the user middle-clicks the link or tries to right-click-bookmark it or whatever.)

If all you want is something that behaves like a button to submit a POST form, better to actually use a real form and submit button, and then use CSS to restyle it to look like a link if that's what you want it to look like.

Comment: Thanks a ton. It worked. Ajax and Jquery are very new to me. So you are suggesting, when js is enabled do "ajax" instead of "post" and when js is disabled reload by "get".

Thats sounds perfect. I really appreciate. If possible can you help me ajax stuff.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Very good hint....

I was first trying to send the form data via an Ajax Post call and reloading the page afterwards, but it was not working properly:

```
var  biq_select_val = jQuery('#biq_search_select').val();
jQuery.post(window.location.href,
        { biq_amazon_item_list_search: biq_select_val},
        function() {window.location.reload();}
    );
```

Now I am using just a:

```
jQuery('#biq_amazon_item_list_search_form').submit();
```

and it is working fine.

Comment: Sometimes the easiest solution is the best.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have some 10 links on a page. When user clicks on those links ajax-reload must take place.

To be clear I have something like this.

```
<a href="test.php?name=one">one</a>
<a href="test.php?name=Two">Two</a>
```

If javascript is enabled,

Onclick, ajax load must take place.

If javascript is disabled, Then the above should work.

Basically I am using `name` to limit some values of my search page.